# Reactjs integrating bootstrap components

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

Here is my simple jsx file, Im trying to integrate bootstap but the components are not rendering - the page is blank.

```
var CreatePanel = React.createClass({ 
    render: function(){ 
        return <div className="row">
            Create Panel

            <div className = "col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style = "background-color: #dedef8;
                box-shadow: inset 1px -1px 1px #444, inset -1px 1px 1px #444;">

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>; 
    } 
}); 

var FilterPanel = React.createClass({ 
    render: function(){ 
        return <div className="row">Filter Panel</div>; 
    } 
}); 

React.render(<div class="container">
    <CreatePanel/>   
    <FilterPanel/> 
</div>
    , document.getElementById('react-container'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using in-line styles properly. Refer to this documentation and let me know if this fixes your problem. https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html